# How to change mime-type of .j2k file to webp using Minimagick?

Tags: ruby, minimagick

I need to change the .j2k image files to webp. I tried using mini-magick but its not changing mime-type to webp. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.
This is the way i tried but this won't convert the mime_type to webp.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("input.jpg")
image.format "webp"
image.write  "output.webp"
```

Comment: I edited my question and added piece of code which i follwed

Comment: got the answer
http://askubuntu.com/questions/251950/imagemagick-convert-cant-convert-to-webp
follwed this link and it worked!!..